# Unity: The type InjectionPolicy cannot be constructed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

This is a puzzle I've been struggling with for hours.  Here's the background:

1. We use `Unity IoC` in an MVC4 web app
2. We have a couple `ApiControllers (IHttpController)` and a bunch of regular controllers (`IController`)
3. Resolution of the `IControllers` works fine
4. Resolution of the `IHttpControllers` has been working fine for months and now fails with the a type resolution error having the details "`The type InjectionPolicy cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value`"
5. Both the regular and Api controllers take an `ICustomerService` dependency which has an `ICustomerRepository` dependency which in turn has an `IClient` dependency, but none of this is new or different.
6. Removing the `ICustomerService` dependency from the `ApiController` solves the problem (but that interface is clearly configured and working everywhere else)
7. We have in place an `HttpControllerActivator` that is registered in Unity and is intercepting calls to resolve the `IHttpControllers` - it fails on container.Resolve, even though looking into the container, the controller is clearly there.

I have searched on this particular error and find nothing.  Has anyone seen it before or does it give you any clues as to what might be going on?

Thanks so much!

UPDATE:  I have narrowed this down to the `ICustomerRepository` resolution (again, working in all other flows).  The error is:

```
Resolving Xxx.CustomerRepository,(none) (mapped from Xxx.ICustomerRepository, (none))
    Resolving Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.PolicyInjectionBehavior,(none)
    Resolving parameter "policies" of constructor Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.PolicyInjectionBehavior(Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.CurrentInterceptionRequest interceptionRequest, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.InjectionPolicy[] policies, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer container)
      Resolving Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.InjectionPolicy[],(none)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the same dll is not loaded twice? I remember having some plugin architecture, and plugins loaded one dll from their folder, and the main container loaded the same dll from different folder. In the end, the result was that the same static class had 2 instances. You may configure unity with the class from dll loaded the first time, then you request an instance from the second dll. In theory, a dll is loaded only once, but if you have an older version in a different folder, then you have 2 versions of the same dll, and they can be loaded by the same runtime.